# Label text changes after refreshing the page using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, label, innerhtml

After refreshing the page the label contenct vanishes.
What should i change so that this won't happen?

```js
var versuche = 3; //login attempts

function validate(){
 var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
 var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
 if ( username == "DjolePhillip" && password == "passwort12345")
 {
  alert ("Login erfolgreich");
  window.location = "loggedin.html";
  document.getElementById("loginname").innerHTML = username; //label gets the username
  return false;
 }
 else{
  versuche --;
  alert("Du hast "+versuche+" uebrig;");
  
  if( versuche == 0)// if no attempts left
        {
   document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
   return false;
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="anmeldung">
 
  <center id="anmeldename"><label id="loginname"></label></center>
 </div>
```

There above is the full Code.

Comment: Store it to localStorage and retrieve it from there upon reload?

Comment: Where is *username* field?!

Comment: @Ali Why does it matter? The question is clear without the username field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the data somewhere. Server side with an ajax request, client side with SessionStorage or LocalStorage.

### Example with LocalStorage

```
var localStorage = window.localStorage

var storedUsername = getUsernameInMemory()
var domUsername = getUsernameDomValue()

var username = storedUsername || domUsername || 'unknown'

if ( !isUsernameDefinedInDOM() ) {
  setLoginname(username)
}
if ( isUsernameKnown() && !isUsernameDefinedInLocalStorage() ) {
  storeUsername(username)
}

function isUsernameKnown () {
  return username !== 'unknown'
}
function setLoginname (_username) {
  document.getElementById('loginname').innerHTML = username
}
function storeUsername (_username) {
  localStorage['username'] = _username
}
function getUsernameDomValue () {
  return document.getElementById('username').value
}
function getUsernameInMemory () {
  return localStorage['username']
}
function isUsernameDefinedInDOM () {
  return !!getUsernameDomValue() // returns a boolean
}
function isUsernameDefinedInLocalStorage () {
  return getUsernameDomValue() !== 'unknown'
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, because it just tells OP to google either technique. Describing the technique is also not an option, since it has been thoroughly described on the Stack Overflow. So you should post this "answer" as comment.

Comment: I tried this out and it didnt work.. nothing happened

Comment: @nicael «This is not an answer, » ... Are you kidding ? Yes it is an answer. I make 3 proposition to solve the problem, and I provide a complete implementation of one of the three. So yes, it is an answer.

Comment: @nicael No, removing semicolons are absolutely correct : [JavaScript Semicolon Insertion
Everything you need to know][http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons]

Comment: @KenKaneki Yes it works, just make a little effort to adapt it to your real situation. This is why I encapsuled all modular functionnality in a specific function, this way you can use them as you really need. There is all you need to solve your problem.